# Which application is used when I open a file item using albert?

Tags: linux, albert

When I open a file X application Y is used to open then file. But I'd rather like to see albert use application Z for it. How can I set the default application albert is using to open particular files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless explicitly defined by the responsible extension, Albert uses the system defaults. These are managed by your desktop environment and defined as stated in the freedesktop.org [Association between MIME types and applications](http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html) standard. See the [Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#MIME_types_and_desktop_entries) or [Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/MIME) wiki for a human readable version of the standard. One generic way to change those associations is `xdg-mime`. But usually your desktop environment offers a convenient way to change these preferences.

<sub>Note: I am the author of this app. This Q&A is part of the migration of the FAQ to the public.</sub>